# What are default objects in main xib?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

Have created a simple view-based iOS app for iPhone in Xcode called HelloUser with two classes, HelloUserAppDelegate and HelloUserViewController. When I opened up HelloUserViewController.xib in IB, there are only three objects: File's Owner, First Responder and View. No HelloUserAppDelegate object. The compiled app runs OK.

Is this normal, or should there be a delegate object? I thought that delegation was an important design pattern in Cocoa and handled many program loading operations including viewDidLoad for File's Owner, so I'm a bit puzzled that there is no delegate object.

Am using version 3.2.5 of IB.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Delegate object by default goes in the `MainWindow.xib` file. Your single view controller isn't responsible for the delegation for the entire app; there should be a delegate object, but not in `HelloUserViewController.xib`.

Comment: OK, thanks. I opened up the MainWindow.xib and saw the HelloUserAppDelegate object there. So that means the HelloUserViewController.xib is the delegate controller under the MainWindow.xib?

Comment: Not quite. The HelloUserAppDelegate class is the delegate for the entire application. There's no such thing as a "delegate controller," but the HelloUserViewController is the first view controller to be created and added to the window.